# azure function to upload multiple files into blob storage

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

```
 public static class FileUpload
    {
        [FunctionName("FileUpload")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
        {
            string Connection = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage");
            string containerName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ContainerName");
            Stream myBlob = new MemoryStream();
            var file = req.Form.Files["File"];
            myBlob = file.OpenReadStream();
            var blobClient = new BlobContainerClient(Connection, containerName);
            var blob = blobClient.GetBlobClient(file.FileName);
            await blob.UploadAsync(myBlob);
            return new OkObjectResult("file uploaded successfylly");
        }
    }
```

This is ok for uploading single file. What would be the best solution to provide multiple files upload using azure function.

Comment: Pass in an array with the contents of each file as well as a name. Then process them one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected result below:

Firstly, I have 3 files in my folder as below:

[image]

**upload_ToBlob Method:**

```
public class AzureBlobSample
{
    public void upload_ToBlob(string fileToUpload, string containerName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inside upload method");

        string file_extension,
        filename_withExtension;
        Stream file;

        string connectionString = @"BlobEndpoint=https://rithwik1.blob.core.windows.net/;QueueEndpoint=https://rithwik1.queue.core.windows.net/;FileEndpoint=https://rithwik1.file.core.windows.net/;TableEndpoint=https://rithwik1.table.core.windows.net/;SharedAccessSignature=sv=2=2023-01-05T1Z&st=2023-01-0n3Cs%3D";

        file = new FileStream(fileToUpload, FileMode.Open);

        CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAcct = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = cloudStorageAcct.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);

        if (container.CreateIfNotExists())
        {

            container.SetPermissionsAsync(new BlobContainerPermissions
            {
                PublicAccess =
              BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
            });

        }

        //reading file name & file extention    
        file_extension = Path.GetExtension(fileToUpload);
        filename_withExtension = Path.GetFileName(fileToUpload);

        CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filename_withExtension);
        var dir = container.GetDirectoryReference("Temp");
        cloudBlockBlob.Properties.ContentType = file_extension;

        cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(file); // << Uploading the file to the blob >>  

        Console.WriteLine("Upload Completed!");


    }
}
```

Now call the **upload_ToBlob** method using below code:

```
AzureBlobSample azureBlob = new AzureBlobSample();

string rootdir = @"C:\Temp\Test\Version2\";

string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(rootdir);

foreach (string file in files)  
{  
azureBlob.upload_ToBlob(file, "rithwik");  
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This function expects the request body to be an array of objects, each containing a name property (the name of the file) and a stream property (a readable stream containing the contents of the file). You can modify the function to suit your specific needs.

```
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from '@azure/functions';
import { BlobServiceClient, StorageSharedKeyCredential } from '@azure/storage-blob';

const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function(context: Context, req: HttpRequest): Promise<void> {
  // Get the list of files from the request body
  const files = req.body;

  // Create a connection to Azure Blob Storage
  const storageAccount = process.env.STORAGE_ACCOUNT;
  const storageAccessKey = process.env.STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY;
  const sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(storageAccount, storageAccessKey);
  const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
    `https://${storageAccount}.blob.core.windows.net`,
    sharedKeyCredential
  );

  // Iterate over the list of files and store each one in Azure Blob Storage
  for (const file of files) {
    // Create a new blob in the specified container
    const containerName = 'my-container';
    const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
    const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(file.name);

    // Upload the contents of the file to the blob
    const stream = file.stream;
    await blockBlobClient.uploadStream(stream, file.size);
  }

  // Return a response to the client
  context.res = {
    status: 200,
    body: 'Successfully uploaded files.'
  };
};

export default httpTrigger;
```

Comment: saves me hours, good code snippet helping to understand how to use stuff learned from azure docs