# Azure Blob Storage Upload: No Exception or Status Returned When File Async Upload Fails

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I've scourged through many answers which suggests usage of a try catch block to catches the StorageException, But for some reason my function did not gave any exception I have multiple files that are being uploaded like this but only one file got succeeded others were not uploaded in my blob storage. (1/10) files got uploaded to designated blob storage.

`

```
public async Task UploadToAzureBlobStorageAsync(Stream stream, string remoteFilePath, string connectionString)
{
    BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
    BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("myblob");

    // Check if the container exists, and if not, create it.
    if (await containerClient.ExistsAsync() == false)
    {
        _logger.LogWarning("Container did not exist in the destination so created a new one");
        await containerClient.CreateAsync();
    }

    BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(remoteFilePath);
    var res = await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream, true);
    _logger.LogInformation($"Uploaded to blob at : {remoteFilePath}");
}
```

`

The timer trigger that calls this function has a try catch block in it so an exception is expected to be caught.

I ran my application after months, I've stopped it for a while is that the cause of the issue (like provisioning e.t.c) ? how to catch this issue programmatically
Atleast printing the status code would suffice.

I tried in my Local its working fine That is why I thought that this might be some kind of provisioning issue. please clear my mind on this one.

Comment: Can you refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75014542). If you still have any requirements please post in above question.

Answer (score 1):

> The timer trigger that calls this function has a try catch block in it so an exception is expected to be caught.

If your Azure Blob Storage upload is not throwing a `StorageException` even when an error occurs can check the HTTP status code returned by the `UploadAsync` method to get more information about the result.

**Code:**

```cs
public async Task UploadToAzureBlobStorageAsync(Stream stream, string remoteFilePath, string connectionString)
{
    try
    {
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("myblob");

        // Check if the container exists, and if not, create it.
        if (await containerClient.ExistsAsync() == false)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("Container did not exist in the destination so created a new one");
            await containerClient.CreateAsync();
        }

        BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(remoteFilePath);
        var res = await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream, true);

        if (res.GetRawResponse().Status == 201) // 201 Created
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Uploaded to blob at : {remoteFilePath}");
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Error uploading to blob at {remoteFilePath}. Status code: {res.GetRawResponse().Status}");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log or handle the exception
        _logger.LogError($"Exception during blob upload: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

I added a check for the HTTP status code (`res.GetRawResponse().Status`) after the upload operation. If the status code is not 201, it indicates an error
`GetRawResponse` method provides HTTP response, and it can be extracting the status code.
I added  `try-catch` block to handle any other exceptions that might occur during the upload.

For any further clarification required refer This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75014542) to upload multiple blobs into storage container.